# Unable to install YUM in SLES-12-0

Tags: linux, yum, sles

When I am trying to install using Zypper,I am getting this error:
 zypper install yum
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'yum' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'yum' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.

Any help is really appreciated.

zypper lr -u

## | Alias       | Name        | Enabled | Refresh |

| SLES12-12-0 | SLES12-12-0 | Yes     | No      |

Comment: Another thing I tried is getting yum-3.4.3-4.1.1.x86_64.rpm and after that  rpm -ivh yum-3.4.3-4.1.1.x86_64.rpm
warning: yum-3.4.3-4.1.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3dbdc284: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        python-gpgme is needed by yum-3.4.3-4.1.1.x86_64
        python-iniparse is needed by yum-3.4.3-4.1.1.x86_64
        python-yum = 3.4.3 is needed by yum-3.4.3-4.1.1.x86_64
        yum-metadata-parser >= 1.1.0 is needed by yum-3.4.3-4.1.1.x86_64

Comment: Why are you trying to install yum in the first place? SLES doesn't use it. What are you *actually* trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to run Rational clearcase, but to install its file system it needs few libraries , which according to technote: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683137    i should proceed in this order.

Comment: Those directions are for RHEL 7. Does IBM not have directions for SLES? If not are you sure it will even *run* on SLES? Is using RHEL (or CentOS?) 7 not an option? All those directions are telling you is the packages that are necessary to have installed. Installing the same packages on SLES should satisfy similarly.

Comment: I have to install it on sles12 , it does work on sles, I have to get those libraries , as they are the dependencies , do you know how can I do that on sles 12 because, I just started using SLES. No clue how to get it done.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps by following the instructions for configuring SLES 12 for Rational Clearcase? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21691807

Comment: Sorry to bug you again: